# How can I find the size of all tables in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have about 50 tables in DynamoDB and I'm looking for a way to find size of all tables.

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name [table name]
```

I know above command returns TableSizeBytes, but is this the only way to get size of table?
Do I have to run this command for all tables in picture?
Also, what is the cost of running this command?

Comment: Yes, run the command for each table, just write a loop, few lines of python code. That endpoint does not cost anything, as is the cast with most management api calls, putting or getting items costs data, getting a table, creating a table, deleting a table, etc. is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a script and loop over all your tables. As already stated there's no cost for running the command.

For example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

YOUR_DYNAMODB_TABLES=( "table1" "table2" "table3" )
TOTAL_SIZE=0
for TABLE in "${YOUR_DYNAMODB_TABLES[@]}"
do
    SIZE=$(aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name "$TABLE" | jq '.Table.TableSizeBytes')
    TOTAL_SIZE=$((TOTAL_SIZE + SIZE))
done
echo $TOTAL_SIZE
```

Comment: You can also have fun with `list-tables` and `xargs` :D

Answer (score 2):

`DescribeTable` API is free to invoke on DynamoDB. Your only way is to iterate through all the tables and sum up the values, but I don't get why that might be an issue.

If you don't want to list all tables by hand, here's a one liner, just for fun:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --region us-east-1 | \
  jq -r '.TableNames[]' | \
  xargs -L1 -I'{}' bash -c 'aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name {} --region us-east-1 | jq -r ".Table.TableSizeBytes"' | \
  awk '{S+=$1} END {print S}'
```

Comment: where do we need  to execute the above script?

Comment: in your terminal.